# Употребление тире для обозначения причины. "Пожалуй" как "может быть"

Tags: синтаксис

> *Она решила не надевать корсет – пожалуй, это оставит плохое
>   впечатление.*

1. Это неверно, если я рассматриваю часть "пожалуй, это оставит плохое впечатление" как причину, по которой героиня предпочла не надевать корсет? Если можно было бы перемодулировать предложение, так было бы правильно: "Она решила не надевать корсет, потому что это могло бы оставить плохое впечатление"?
2. Можно утверждать, что "пожалуй" можно интерпретировать как "может быть", "наверное", "скорее всего" в этом контексте?

Большое спасибо!

Comment: у меня другои keyboard, извините! сеичас через copy&paste сделаю, момент

Answer (score 3):

Вы верно интерпретируете, но возможно оставить и тире, Лопатин это допускает в ПАС:

http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=417#pg417

Примечание 2. В бессоюзном сложном предложении при обозначении пояснения, причины, обоснования, изъяснения допустимо употребление тире вместо двоеточия (особенно в художественной литературе и в публицистике). Вот, в частности, примеры из произведений К. Паустовского: Подснежники, наверное, уже прорастали в земле — их слабый травянистый запах просачивался сквозь снег; Слой облаков был очень тонок — сквозь него просвечивало солнце;Татьяна Андреевна вздрагивала от сырости — после теплой каюты на палубе было свежо; Паханов крепко держал капитана за локоть — капитан был еще слаб после ранения; Ей хотелось заплакать — лом даже через варежки леденил руки; В армию меня тоже не берут — сердце заштопанное; Однажды зимой вышел я и слышу — стонет кто-то за оградой.

Примеры из произведений современных авторов и из периодической печати:Думать мне пришлось недолго — дверь распахнулась, и я увидел Чапаева(Пелев.); В дом попасть никто не мог — двери и окна были закрыты (газ.);Доски гнулись и ходили ходуном под его ботинками — он был тяжелым, а пол старым (Уст.); Мы ее Барбариска звали — она вечно всех детей карамелью угощала... (Улиц.). То же при глаголах, требующих пояснения:Вскинул голову — у порога стоит Мария (Шукш.); А помню — в сугробах тонули дворы (Сн.); Казалось мне — с любовью строгой она глядит из-под бровей (Лис); Она испуганно осмотрелась —

Answer (score 1):

**Она решила не надевать корсет – пожалуй, это оставит плохое впечатление.**

**Сравним с другими вариантами** (только прямая речь, только авторские слова):

(1) Она подумала: "Если я надену корсет, то это, скорее всего, оставит плохое впечатление".
(2) Она решила не надевать корсет. "Пожалуй, это оставит плохое впечатление" - подумалось ей.
(3) Она решила не надевать корсет, потому что это могло бы оставить плохое впечатление.

И вернемся к авторскому варианту: **изящная грамматика, лучшее решение**. Это, действительно, несобственно-прямая речь, еще Пушкин ею пользовался.

**О несобственно-прямой речи**

Несобственно-прямая речь (НПР)  – это часть текста, передающая слова, мысли, чувства персонажа, которая оформлена особым образом. НПР  **совмещает свойства прямой и косвенной  (авторской) речи.**Этот прием часто используется в художественной литературе и публицистике, когда автору нужно показать своего героя как бы изнутри, дать читателю услышать его внутренний голос.

**Текстовые примеры**
Но вот его комната. Ничего и никого, никто не заглядывал. Даже Настасья не притрагивалась. Но, Господи! Как мог он оставить давеча все эти вещи в этой дыре? Он бросился в угол, запустил руку под обои и стал вытаскивать вещи и нагружать ими карманы  (Ф. Достоевский).

Answer (score 0):

"Пожалуй" (как и "видимо" или "наверное") выражает позицию персонажа (в 1-м лице) и не подходит для авторской трактовки причины. Поэтому фразу нужно строить так, чтобы это слово явно относилось к мыслям персонажа. Скорее всего, не обойтись без введения прямой речи:

> Она решила не надевать корсет. "Пожалуй, это оставит плохое
>   впечатление" - подумалось ей.

Ваш перефразированный вариант возможен, но для более точного сохранения смысла полезно было бы добавить вводный оборот "в её понимании" и т. п.

Comment: Почему ж не обойтись? Можно и обойтись, как вот в этом случае - несобственно-прямая речь.1 часть -авторская речь, 2-мысли  героини. "Пожалуй" - слово героини, средство речевой характеристики. Потому здесь и тире, что оно делит предложение на 2 части.http://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik/107-nesobstvenno-pryamaya-68427.html

Comment: Я не случайно сделал оговорку "скорее всего": на мой субъективный взгляд, в этом предложении такой переход стилистически неудачен, поскольку при однократном прочтении трудно разобрать, то ли по небрежности произошёл переход к изложению с позиции автора, то ли по ходу предложения автор и впрямь "художественно перевоплотился" в своего персонажа. Это вопрос чувства меры автора.